# Django: make stringed byte-string back to original

Tags: django

I make some application with a new `users` model and `email` as login. I have simple confirmation with users email.

The plan is:

1. User enters his or her data; `email` of course.
2. Next He receives some code (formed as `urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(users_email))`).
3. This code is planned to be entered by hand or with copy-paste in confirm field. to make users account active.

In python console this chain works good.

The problem is: when user enters by hand or copy-paste the code from email, it raises

```
DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte... 
  You passed in b'm\xb5\xa5\xad\xb...
```

Some analysis shows that in post function the code arrives as string `"b'bla-bla-bla"`. But not as byte-string `b'bla-bla-bla'`, which is good for getting original string with `force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(the_code))`.

Any ideas to convert the string object with `b` starting symbol to more comfortable byte-string object? Or there is another way to make some secret encoding/decoding based on user-name (user-email) ?

Answer (score 0):

PS:
I just figured - to split receiving string, and make new byte-string like `force_bytes(the_code.split("'")[1])`.
Is there any more delicate or pythonic method?